# Dogs constant paw licking

Tags: dogs, health

My dog has been licking and pulling out fur on paws for years. He’s been to the vet so many times and they’ve tried different steroids and now a steroid spray too. I’ve noticed 3 red sore lumps now on his paws which is worrying.

Answer (score 1):

This screams allergies that need to be addressed fast.

This is typically how allergies can manifest themselves in dogs.

The solution to this would be look at and change their diet and have some reputable allergy tests at the vet. This will fix the problem.

Steroids can have effects on the immune system. And only surprise the symptoms of allergies and not the actual cause.